# Inline images not showing up in office 365 outlook in browser

Tags: office365

I'm opening a mail in Office 365. The problem is that the e-mail body has an image and the img does not display correctly because of its src.
and I found out that outlook wep app changes the src attribute to an url.
By this image got distorted and can see the horizontal line just below the logo.
And Faded color also

[image]

url is composed  by: https://outlook.office365.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetFileAttachment?id=ATTACHMENT'S ID%3D&X-OWA-CANARY=SOMETHING THAT I DON'T KNOW WHAT IT IS

Ideally, the image should be like below:

[image]
Any ideas about how can I show the correct images?